# iSCSI latency under load with ESXi 6.0u2

Tags: vmware, iscsi

***Short question:*** Why am I experiencing write latency of 150ms on an iSCSI LUN on ESXi 6.0 update2, when the network is saturated. (Both SCST and LIO)

***Longer:***

Ubuntu 16.04(4.4.0-77) with LIO Target connected to VMWare ESXi with 2 ip addresses in round robin PSP. The performance is quite excellent *except* for the latency. I get 12k random write iops, 30k random read iops. 220MB/s sequential reads and writes.

However,
sequential writes incur 150-200ms latency(sometimes reads too), and I don't understand why? Random operations incur 1-5ms latency. So it appears to be network related ? But surely not.

I've tested **ssd disks** and a **ramdisk** with LIO iSCSI, and also with SCST iSCSI Target, all the same. I tuned the heck out of the parameters and the best I could come up with was a stable 150ms.

Also not that I am using Intel QUAD Gigabit server nics, jumbo frames and flow control enabled on the switch. There are no errors or dropped packets on any interfaces.

Could someone share with me their latency on the LUN while pushing Gigabit speeds ? Or anything.